# Implement the factory pattern with the Zend Plugin Manager

Tags: php, zend-framework3

The function `createInstance(String $instance) : InstanceInterface{}` should return an instance of `IntanceInterface`. I don't want to use a switch statement because there are so many instances (different classes) . Though a friend told me about the Plugin Manager in Zend-Framework 3. 
I read about Service Manager as they seem to be related.

https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Website_Operation/Plugin_Managers.html

Instead of the Plugin Manager the Service Manager is well documented and described.

I think I implemented it the wrong way because I get an php error:

`Deprecated: Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager::__construct now expects a Interop\Container\ContainerInterface instance representing the parent container; please update your code in /website/admin/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php on line 85`

`Warning: ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /website/admin/vendor/zendframework/zend-session/src/Config/SessionConfig.php on line 148`

InstanceFactory

```
protected $instancePluginManager;

public function __construct(InstancePluginManager $instacePluginManager)
    {
        $this->instancePluginManager = $instancePluginManager;
    }


public function createInstance(string $instance) :InstanceInterface
    {

       $this->instacePluginManager->get($instance);
}
```

InstancePluginManager

```
class InstancePluginManager extends AbstractPluginManager
{


    protected $instanceOf = InstanceInterface::class;

    /**
     * @var string[]|callable[] Default factories
     */
    protected $factories = [

        A::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        B::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        C::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        D::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        E::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        F::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        G::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        H::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        I::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        J::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ];

    public function validate($instance)
    {
        if (! $instance instanceof $this->instanceOf) {
            throw new InvalidServiceException(sprintf(
                'Chart of type "%s" is invalid; must implement %s',
                (is_object($instance) ? get_class($instance) : gettype($instance)),
                $this->instanceOf
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

InstanceFactoryFactory (Zend Factory)

```
class InstanceFactoryFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $instancePluginManager = $container->get(InstancePluginManager::class);

        return new InstanceFactory($instancePluginManager);
    }
}
```

module.config.php

```
return [
'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
InstanceFactory::class => InstanceFactoryFactory::class,
InstancePluginManager::class => InvokableFactory::class,

],
],
];
```

Comment: The message means that you should update your `AbstractPluginManager::__construct()` function. It currently requires an instance of `InstancePluginManager`, but it should be `ContainerInterface`. The `Warning: ini_set() [...]` error is because your most likely doing a var_dump or something, else it's caused by the sending of the error layout and you're trying to do something afterwards, like creating a new layout. This is resolved by properly catching errors you create / can occur ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
InstancePluginManager::class => InvokableFactory::class
```

to

```
InstancePluginManager::class => function (ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName) {
    return new InstancePluginManager($container);
}
```

The InvokableFactory is trying to create your InstancePluginManager with no arguments.